# What are the conjugacy classes in $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, group-actions

Let $G$ be an arbitrary group, and let $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ be the group of automorphisms of $G$ (with composition of morphisms as multiplication).

I'd like to learn more about the problem of characterizing the conjugacy classes $C_T$ (where the indexing variable $T$ ranges over $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$):

$$C_T = \{U\in \mathrm{Aut}(G) \mid (\;\exists\, S \in \mathrm{Aut}(G) \mid S \;{\scriptstyle \circ} \; T \;{\scriptstyle \circ}\;S^{-1} = U \; )\}  $$

of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$.

I know absolutely *nothing* about this problem.  (In fact, for all I know, the problem is too hard—or too easy—to even bring up in polite company.)

What (keywords, books, papers, authors, etc.) should I search for to learn more about this problem?

Comment: The problem, as currently phrased, seems to easy/hard to answer. There are very few special techniques for this case. If $Z(G)=1$ then one can relate the conjugacy classes of $G$ to those of $\newcommand{\Aut}{\operatorname{Aut}}\Aut(G)$; this is generally called fusion and in some sense this is easy. In general, it is a relationship between conjugacy classes of $G/Z(G)$ and $\Aut(G)$ which is two (basically easy) fusion problems in a row. If $G$ is finite non-abelian simple, then this is fairly well studied. The ATLAS is nice reference for the small cases and GL2 or GLS are good in general.

Answer (score 1):

There's no particular reason that understanding conjugacy classes in an automorphism group would be any easier or harder than understanding conjugacy classes in any other group.  There's also not really any general theory for understanding conjugacy -- you mostly just have to do it one group at a time.  In fact, I would say that understanding conjugacy in a group usually has more to do with understanding the group well than with having a good general understanding of conjugacy .

To given an example of the difficulty, suppose that $G$ is a nonabelian [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group).  Then the conjugacy problem in [the automorphism group of $G$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aut(F_n)) is fairly difficult. (See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150722/is-the-conjugacy-problem-solvable-in-outf-n) on Math Overflow, which pertains to the slightly different problem of conjugacy in the *outer* automorphism group of a free group).